# Is it possible to output the ADF test in a table?

Tags: time-series, visualization

I want to check my variables for stationarity. I am using the adf.test() method from tseries.

I tried:

```
adf_results <- list(
  Vola = adf.test(data$Vola),
  Supply = adf.test(data$Supply),
  Tweets = adf.test(data$Tweets))

modelsummary(adf_results)
```

But it is not working. Is there some other way to get it as a PNG to add it to libre writer?